# Strange border on tabIndex on <p> element

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabindex

I'm currently trying to make some show/hide content more accessible on a large site (in excess of 30,000 pages) and I've come across a weird bug when adding tabindex where a dotted border appears when clicking on the control to open the hidden content.

The set up with *p* tag which you click to fadeIn a *div* which shows the hidden content. **I can't modify the HTML at all due to there being thousands of these across the site** so this is what I have to work with. At the moment to add tabindex i'm doing it dynamically with jQuery, adding an ever increasing tab index to each *p* tag.

My first though to get rid of this weird border was to try CSS:

```
#content div.showHide p.showHideTitle:focus, 
#content div.showHide p.showHideTitle::focus, 
#content div.showHide p.showHideTitle::-moz-focus-border {
    outline: 0px !important; border: 0px !important;
}
```

This works in Chrome and Safari but in IE8 and Firefox 3.6 I still get the border when I click on the *p* tag. Any suggestions for how to get rid of it?

Comment: I don't get it. How does hiding the outline to stop keyboard only users knowing where the focus is help with accessibility?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

whats about:

```
#content div.showHide p.showHideTitle {
    outline: none !important; 
}
```

You are setting the outline style for the pseudo class `:focus` but this may be "to late".
Here a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GPnxS/)

Answer (score 7):

I have a better solution to this issue, hybrid javascript/css.

```
$('[tabindex]').focus(function()
{
    $(this).css('outline', 'none');
});
$('[tabindex]').keyup(function (event)
{
    if(event.keyCode == 9)
    {
        $(this).css('outline', '');
    }
});
```

This way it still works if you tab through, but not if you click.

Comment: +1 This is wonderful. Just what I needed. Still want `[tabindex]` to highlight when tabbing, but it really is annoying for togglers to get that annoying outline when mouse-clicking. This will go into my bag-o-tricks!

Answer (score 6):

Although not the most efficient CSS selector by any means you can remove this from all DOM elements with tabindex attributes just the following CSS:

```
[tabindex] {
   outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `css` with your script?  Something like

```
$("#content div.showHide p.showHideTitle").focus(function () {
     $(this).css('border','0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

But, the user should see the outline when focused by tab press.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="className" tabIndex="1" style={{outline: 0}}>
    <p> Try this... I hope this works!</p>
<div>
```

Comment: A written explanation as to why this may work where other answers have failed would be appreciated.